# Error con Hibernate haciendo un delete

Tags: java, netbeans, hibernate

estoy recien empezando en el uso de hibernate, ya puedo listar,agregar y modificar registros pero me surgio el siguiente error al intentar hacer un delete:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: persona is not mapped

este es mi metodo de delete

```
public static void eliminarDatos(int id)
{
    Session sesion = null;
    sesion = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    sesion.beginTransaction();
    String HQL = "delete from persona where idpersona = :idpersona";
    Query query;
    query = sesion.createQuery(HQL);
    query.setInteger("idpersona", id);
    System.out.println(query.executeUpdate());   

}
```

y este es mi hbm de la tabla persona

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 29-01-2019 15:46:26 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="modelo_hibernate.Persona" table="persona" catalog="mybd" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="idpersona" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="idpersona" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="nombre" type="string">
            <column name="nombre" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="apellido" type="string">
            <column name="apellido" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="direccion" type="string">
            <column name="direccion" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="telefono" type="string">
            <column name="telefono" length="45" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

alguna ayuda o sugerencia con respecto al tema??

Comment: No es una respuesta como tal a tu pregunta pero quizas te seria mas facil mapear la tabla  usando anotaciones(jpa annotations) en lugar de usar xml.

Comment: intente lo que me decías @JosemyAB y efectivamente funciona sin errores pero el delete no se ejecuta, osea, el método funciona y incluso me envía el mensaje de (borrado) pero el registro que debería borrar sigue ahí, alguna sugerencia?

Comment: utilice las anotaciones y funciona bien pero aun no resuelvo el tema

Comment: Quizas me estoy llendo por las ramas pero podrias subir un ejemplo de tu proyecto con las misma configuraciones que tienes actualmente a un repo github para intentar analizar bien tu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando usas HQL para las consultas tienes que respetar las mayusculas y minúsculas. Este "lenguaje" es camelCase.

Veo que en tu query: `String HQL = "delete from persona where idpersona = :idpersona";` haces referencia a un objeto "persona" (con minúsculas). Dado que esa entidad es un objeto de Java, debes nombrarla con la primera letra en mayúscula, que es como tienes declarada la clase (modelo_hibernate.**P**ersona)

Quedaría así:

```
String HQL = "delete from Persona where idpersona = :idpersona";
```